# Bulls and Cows Game - Python programming for beginners

Tags: python

I am a beginer programming Python and for a evaluation assignment I was asked to program a Bulls and Cows game using very simple code.
I have some code already written, but can't seem to make the function work. The function should be able to compare the four digit number the user wrote (num_guess) to the random number generated by the program (stored in a list called num).
I can input the value, but have no further feedback from the program. 
Could you please check my code and help me?
Thanks!

```
import random

guess = raw_input("What is your guess? ") 
if (len(guess) != 4): 
    guess = raw_input("Your guess must be 4 characters long! What is your guess?")

num_guess = []  
for c in guess:  
    num_guess.append(int(c)) 

def compare(num_guess):
    num = []  
    for i in range(4):  
        n = random.randint(0, 9)  
        while n in num: 
            n = random.randint(0, 9)
        num.append(n)

 if num_guess == num: 
     print "Congratulations! Your guess is correct"

 output = []

 if num_guess[0] == num [0]:
    output.append["B"]
 else:
     output.append["C"]

 if num_guess[1] == num [1]:
     output.append["B"]
 else:
     output.append["C"] 

 if num_guess[2] == num [2]:
     output.append["B"]
 else:
     output.append["C"] 

 if num_guess[3] == num [3]:
     output.append["B"]
 else:
     output.append["C"]

 return output

nguesses = 0
while nguesses < 11:
nguesses = nguesses + 1, compare
```

Comment: Are you sure that is your code?

Comment: Yes it is, I wrote it myself.
Had a little help from my professor with the first if, nothing else

Answer (score 0):

Without giving you the corrected code you will want to call the function at the end of your code. If you want to see result do:

```
print compare(num_guess)
```

This will show you an additional issue with all of these parts

```
output.append[]
```

I'm not sure if it is just how you pasted it but you may want to clean up the indentation. Also:

```
while n in num: 
        n = random.randint(0, 9)
```

This above section is not needed. Have fun and figure out how to make it work well.

Comment: Thank you! I will let you know when I try it

Comment: I tried it and found out my mistake - I had to use parenthesis and not square brackets in "output.append"
Still figuring out some things.
Many thanks for your help!